# change color in css without adding a new class?

Tags: html, css

I have a calss named .item, which is highly complex..  I want to change the hover color only without copying all the class name to a another name just to change the hover color.  What is the easist way to change the color 000000 to FC0000?

```
.item-test a.hover .thumb {
    border-bottom-color: #000000;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    border-left-color-ltr-source: physical;
    border-left-color-rtl-source: physical;
    border-left-color-value: #000000;
    border-left-style-ltr-source: physical;
    border-left-style-rtl-source: physical;
    border-left-style-value: solid;
    border-left-width-ltr-source: physical;
    border-left-width-rtl-source: physical;
    border-left-width-value: 5px;
    border-right-color-ltr-source: physical;
    border-right-color-rtl-source: physical;
    border-right-color-value: #000000;
    border-right-style-ltr-source: physical;
    border-right-style-rtl-source: physical;
    border-right-style-value: solid;
    border-right-width-ltr-source: physical;
    border-right-width-rtl-source: physical;
    border-right-width-value: 5px;
    border-top-color: #000000;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 5px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: `Wall of CSS attacks YOU, dealing 28 lines of damage! Your [Relic of Refactoring] prevents 21 lines of damage.`

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new CSS definition:

```
.item-test a.hover .thumb:hover {
    border-color: #FC0000;
}
```

The selector used here, `.item-test a.hover .thumb:hover` is more specific than the one used above (because it has an additional *pseudo class*), hence it will have priority over it. See [CSS 2 – The Cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).

Answer (score 1):

That is probably the least efficient CSS I've ever seen...

```
.item-test a.hover .thumb{
    border: 5px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Would do the same thing.

To make a change for hover, you would just do:

```
.item-test a.hover .thumb:hover{
    border-color:#FC0000;
}
```

However, some browsers do not support the :hover psuedo class unless it is an achor. Fortunately it seems as though you have a .thumb nested in an achor, so you should instead do this to assure full compatability:

```
.item-test a:hover .thumb:hover{
    border-color:#FC0000;
}
```

Comment: "some browsers" = IE6, which most people don't care about anymore. If you do care, you can use [Whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html) to fix it.

Comment: Also IE7 in quirks mode. I'm against adding JS to fix what can be worked around with CSS, but that's just me.